# I want to send HTML emails from my site, but Outlook is flagging them as spam

Tags: php, html, email

How to get Outlook to approve my email and not treat it as spam?

I read it's something to do with the headers; here is my email headers.

```
Received: from smtp-in-75.livemail.co.uk (213.171.216.76) by
 exch-ht02.email.local (10.44.216.65) with Microsoft SMTP Server id
 14.1.355.2; Fri, 25 Nov 2011 12:16:47 +0000
Received: from virus_14.livemail.co.uk (virus-cluster.livemail.co.uk
 [213.171.216.10])  by smtp-in-75.livemail.co.uk (Postfix) with SMTP id
 22A126540B7    for <info@cash-access.com>; Fri, 25 Nov 2011 12:16:45 +0000 (GMT)
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.2.5 (2008-06-10) on
    spam_208.livemail.co.uk
X-Spam-Level: **********
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=10.6 required=5.0 tests=FH_FROM_CASH,
    HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_12,HTML_MESSAGE,HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG,MIME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY,
    MIME_HTML_ONLY shortcircuit=no autolearn=disabled version=3.2.5
X-Spam-Report: *  3.0 FH_FROM_CASH From name has "cash"
    *  2.6 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_12 BODY: HTML: images with 800-1200 bytes of words
    *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
    *  2.3 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
    *  1.0 MIME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY 'Content-Type' found without required MIME
    *      headers
    *  1.7 HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG HTML-only message, but there is no HTML tag
Received: from cust-smtp-193.fasthosts.net.uk (smtp-out-60.livemail.co.uk
 [213.171.216.60])  by smtp-in-165.livemail.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id
 710E5EB00B9    for <info@cash-access.com>; Fri, 25 Nov 2011 12:16:40 +0000 (GMT)
Received: from linweb04.linvh1.fasthosts.co.uk (unknown [88.208.252.195])   by
 cust-smtp-193.fasthosts.net.uk (Postfix) with ESMTP id 27B5F14100A9;   Fri, 25
 Nov 2011 12:16:40 +0000 (GMT)
Received: by linweb04.linvh1.fasthosts.co.uk (Postfix, from userid 1040243723)
    id 21D2A1F609; Fri, 25 Nov 2011 12:16:40 +0000 (GMT)
To: <info@cash-access.com>
Subject: -----SPAM----- Your Pension Backed Loan Enquiry
From: <info@cash-access.com>
Content-Type: text/html
CC: <stevewolfe71@gmail.com>
Message-ID: <20111125121640.21D2A1F609@linweb04.linvh1.fasthosts.co.uk>
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2011 12:16:40 +0000
X-Spam-Prev-Subject: Your Pension Backed Loan Enquiry
X-Original-To: info@cash-access.com
X-AntiVirus: checked by Vexira MailArmor
Return-Path: user_1040238723@linweb04.linvh1.fasthosts.co.uk
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: exch-ht02.email.local
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

And here is my php code.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$date = date('y-m-d h:i:s');


$recipient = $_GET['email'];
$lname = $_GET['lname'];
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
$title = $_GET['title'];

    $to = $recipient; 
    $from = "info@cash-access.com"; 
    $subject = "Your Pension Backed Loan Enquiry"; 

    $message = '
<p>Dear '.$title.' '.$fname.' '.$lname.'<u></u><u></u></p>
<p><u></u></p>
<p>We have received your enquiry from Pension Backed Loans and we will be in contact with you to discuss your requirements alternatively you can call us on 01202 763339.<u></u><u></u></p>
<p><u></u> <u></u></p>
<p>Yours sincerely<u></u><u></u></p>
<p><strong>Joanne Hearn<u></u><u></u></strong></p>
<p>Cash Access<u></u><u></u></p>
<p>7a Milburn Road<u></u><u></u></p>
<p>Westbourne<u></u><u></u></p>
<p>Bournemouth<u></u><u></u></p>
<p>Dorset BH4 9HJ<u></u><u></u></p>
<p><u></u> <u></u></p>
<p>t: <a href="tel:%2B44%280%291202%20763339" value="+441202763339" target="_blank">+44(0)1202 763339</a><u></u><u></u></p>
<p>e: <a href="mailto:info@cash-access.com" target="_blank">info@cash-access.com</a><u></u><u></u></p>
<p>w: <a href="http://www.cash-access.com/" target="_blank">www.cash-access.com</a><u></u><u></u></p>
<p><u></u> <img src="http://cash-access.com/crm/logo.png" width="288" height="72" /></p>
'; 
    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

    $headers .= "Cc: stevewolfe71@gmail.com"; 

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Consider using a library like PHPMailer to generate valid mails for you. Plus: Include the text from the HTML part as a plain text part - not all email clients support HTML mails.

Comment: Hi have u you used phpmailer? im thinking of trying to get it to work as my other attempts at email are failing :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not Outlook but the spam filter of *livemail.co.uk* that flags your message as spam.

And it tells you why:

```
3.0 FH_FROM_CASH From name has "cash"
```

Obviously cannot be fixed.

```
2.6 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_12 BODY: HTML: images with 800-1200 bytes of words
```

Either remove the image or increase the word count.

```
0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
```

No impact. No need to get fixed.

```
2.3 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
```

You should always send multipart messages (containg a non-HTML version). [Here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2681) is a tutorial.

```
1.0 MIME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY 'Content-Type' found without required MIME headers
```

Should get fixed by sending a proper multipart message.

```
1.7 HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG HTML-only message, but there is no HTML tag
```

Add an *<html>* tag.

The larger the leading number (weight), the bigger the impact.

Depending on the spam filter's configuration, the following may decrease the weight:

- Apply for an entry in a whitelist (e.g., [dnswl.org](http://dnswl.org)).
- Add [Sender Policy Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) (SPF) records.
- Use [DomainKey Identified Mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) (DKIM).

Comment: how can i fix all the parts apart from the cash bit?

Comment: I have got it down to 7.9 now, it need to be 5 or under,

Comment: 2.6 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_12 BODY: HTML: images with 800-1200 bytes of words
 *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
 *  2.3 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts

Comment: HI dennis have create like 40 dirrent test emails now and they all get 0 on the span detector but when i try to put a website link in they still get put in the spam box :( any suggestions

Comment: Besides the method I have already suggested (whitelist, SPF, DKIM), only one (and you will not like it): Change your host name! `cash-access.com` simply sounds like spam. To spam filters and humans alike. When I read the host name in your first question, the first thing I did was checking some domain name based blacklists to see if you are not a spammer.

Comment: Well i did mention to the others when we bourgh that domain its going to get flaged as spam, but we hoped with time hotmail alike will start seeing us as not a spammer

Comment: There are many different spam filters out there. Not all are "learning" ones. And you have to worry about potential customers too. I would never click on a link called *cash access*. It is like trying to raffle a car on your website. Decades of spamming made it difficult...

Comment: Well we speak to our customers on the phone and them email them a covering letter, i was trying to make our system do it automatically, but outlook doesn't want to know.

Comment: added my SPF records now to test it

Answer (score 4):

You didn't set MIME type in your header - when sending html emails you must set it like this:

```
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
```

Also make sure you set `reply-to` header the same as `from` header:

```
$headers  .= 'Reply-To: info@cash-access.com' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$headers = "From:".$from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: some@example.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using SPF records in your DNS to verify your email server, this will make the email much more trusted than just looking at it's contents. Some servers (e.g. hotmail) will reject your email straight-up without it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting your site on a shared server, then your email won't actually be coming from `cash-access.com`, but instead from your host's email server, and will be signed as such.  Outlook (and email providers, such as Gmail) see that the actual sender doesn't match the `from` address.  You need to update SPF records (you can do this via cPanel, if your host has it installed) to rectify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Words like **cash** and **virus** in your content are likely to flag this as spam in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Generally with sending messages you need to send from the same server as the email domain or use an send command that send via the email domains smtp server which is most often the case when using web hotels or if you don't have the email server on the same virtual/physical server.
If you don't have a smtp server to send from a free solution is to make a gmail: http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server