# JavaMail BASE64_LENGTH_79_INF spam

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

when I try to send an email via javamail api, the mail to receipent goes to spam. The reasons are the `BASE64_LENGTH_79_INF` and
`MIME_HTML_ONLY`

```
public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String body, File filename ) {
        String Host = "ip";

        java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", Host);

        javax.mail.Session mailSession = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("some@email"));
            InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
            message.setSubject(subject);



        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

         // Now set the actual message
         messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

         // Create a multipar message
         Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

         // Set text message part
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

         // Part two is attachment
         messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

         DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);

         messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
         System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
         System.out.println(filename.getName());
         messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename.getName());
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

         // Send the complete message parts
         message.setContent(multipart);     

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);

         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is there way to pass this?

Thank you

Comment: The criteria that are used by a spam filter program are completely dependent on that program.

Answer (score 0):

MIME_HTML_ONLY is covered in: [I want to send HTML emails from my site, but Outlook is flagging them as spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269067/i-want-to-send-html-emails-from-my-site-but-outlook-is-flagging-them-as-spam)

If you base64 encode your message body part JavaMail uses a [default of 76 bytes per line](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/blob/4cc00ac06eaa57fbd508a98fbba24b827e02fe5e/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/util/BASE64EncoderStream.java#L78). Try to base64 encode your message body part before you attach it.